# Unable to write textclip with moviepy due to errors with Imagemagick

Tags: python, ffmpeg, imagemagick, moviepy, video-subtitles

I am trying to write TextClip into a video with moviepy. It has always been working, yet after I reinstalled ffmpeg, it doesn't work anymore (I am not sure whether it has caused it, but I mentioned it in case it does). Some of the TextClip objects are pure spaces.

I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1137, in __init__
    subprocess_call(cmd, logger=None)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\moviepy\tools.py", line 54, in subprocess_call
    raise IOError(err.decode('utf8'))
OSError: magick.exe: no images for write '-write' 'PNG32:C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmnf0fkb5.png' at CLI arg 14 @ error/operation.c/CLINoImageOperator/4893.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "media_main_user.py", line 79, in <module>
    insert_audio_and_subtitles(input_clip,'output.mp4','text.mp3',subtitles,fontsize=subtitles_font_size,
  File "D:\UserData\Desktop\Project\影片剪輯\關鍵字版本\make_media.py", line 318, in insert_audio_and_subtitles
    annotated_clips = [annotate(video.subclip(from_t, to_t), txt) for (from_t, to_t), txt in subtitles]
  File "D:\UserData\Desktop\Project\影片剪輯\關鍵字版本\make_media.py", line 318, in <listcomp>
    annotated_clips = [annotate(video.subclip(from_t, to_t), txt) for (from_t, to_t), txt in subtitles]
  File "D:\UserData\Desktop\Project\影片剪輯\關鍵字版本\make_media.py", line 311, in annotate
    txtclip = TextClip(txt, fontsize=fontsize, font=font, color=txt_color)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1146, in __init__
    raise IOError(error)
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

magick.exe: no images for write '-write' 'PNG32:C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmnf0fkb5.png' at CLI arg 14 @ error/operation.c/CLINoImageOperator/4893.
.

.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect
```

I have tried to solve the problems multiple ways, like checking the `config-default.py` file in moviepy installation directory, and the path for ImageMagick it's pointing to is not wrong. I tried to reinstall ImageMagick, it is also of no use. And I tried to edit the `policy.xml` file in ImageMagick directory from `none` to `read|write`, but it also doesn't work. Can anyone suggest other possible solutions?

Comment: You ran some code we can't see and it didn't work? It's very hard to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` try to comment out the following line altogether:

`<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" />`

Like so:

`<!-- <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" /> -->`